# Get number of rows deleted using DROP partition

Tags: oracle, plsql

*A dump question*

Need to get number of rows deleted when delete the data using DROP PARTITION in Oracle DB.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name> DROP PARTITION PART_<Name>;
```

No suggestion like "Get the count in first place and then use DROP PARTITION"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle counting rows in a PARTITION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636475/oracle-counting-rows-in-a-partition)

Comment: `drop partition` doesn't delete the data. It removes partition from the table and "frees" the space occupied by segment (marks as free space). It doesn't process each row. You cannot obtain the number of rows in the (already) non-existing object.

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` is not the same as `DELETE` and you will not get the number of rows that were initially in the partition before it was dropped, therefore if you want to have this metric you will need to have it preseleted.

If you don't want to manually count them, the closest you can get is from using `DBSM_STATS` api in order to populate the num_rows:

```
SELECT NUM_ROWS
  FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS;
```

This is inferior to selecting the counts for each partition, but it's an alternative none the less that somehow fits in your description (or at least so it seems to me).